# Uable to compile aspect jar file

Tags: java, tomcat7, aspectj

All,

I am trying to compile aspect jar file for the logging aspect.

I have created an aspectj project in eclipse and able to see aspectj working fine for logging before and after method advice. Tested it.. works fine.

Now I have a web-project and I want to apply the same aspect( above ) to apply to my web-project.

I am trying to compile the above project to a jar file and include it in the server(Tomcat in this case) jar.

But I am not able to compile the jar. below is build.xml

```
<project name="aspectlogger" default="dist">
<property name="root" value="/." />
<property name="src.dir" value="${root}/src" />
<property name="dist.dir" value="${root}/dist" />
<target name="dist">
<taskdef  classpath="lib/aspectjtools.jar"    resource="org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties"></taskdef>
<iajc source="1.6" target="1.6" showweaveinfo="true" verbose="true" outxml="true" debug="true" outjar="${dist.dir}/logger.jar">
        <argfiles>
                <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
        </argfiles>
        <classpath>
                <path refid="${root}/lib" />
        </classpath>
</iajc>
</target>
</project>
```

But I get the following error;
Could not load definitions from resource org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties. It could not be found.

I have the aspectjtools.jar but it does not contain the aspectjTaskdefs.properties. I googled around it but could not find the jar that contains it.

Please suggest?

Comment: You should write and provide that file by yourself then :) First try to make an empty file, you'll probably get an exception. In that case, try googling something like "aspectJ configuration example".

Comment: Thanks for explanation, shouldn't that be part of the aspectjtools.jar file? I mean the package definition has been defined org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties. If I define my file and provide implementation will that work or it aspectj defined?

Comment: I think it should. But there is definitley a reason why it isnt' - be it that someone forgot to pack it, or there is some good reason. I'm not sure how resource attribute works (can you point it to an external file) - but you could unpack the jar, place the props in the defined place and pack it back again. If the props are correctly defined it most likley should work. I ve heard about AspectJ for the first time now, so I can't help u much - I'm just telling u what I would do in your place :)